# Is there a way to pass properly a string containing a "?" to .net core web api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following action that gets a Question model from my API given the Question title from an autocomplete input. The action is working fine with titles that do not contain a question mark (Ex. How old are you). But if I give a title containing a question mark (Ex. How old are you?) the model is not returned as the question mark is being removed in the process.

I tried `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` method but with no luck .

Below you can find my requests

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetQuestionAsync(string question) {
    Questions q = new Questions();
    HttpClient client = _api.Initial();
    HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("api/Search/" + question);
    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Questions>(result);
    }
    return View(q);
}

[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("{keyword}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByString([FromRoute(Name = "keyword")] string keyword) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var question = await _context.Questions
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Question == HttpUtility
            .UrlDecode(keyword.ToString()));

    if (question == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(question);
}
```

I expect to be able to get questions including `?` from my API. Is there a way to achieve this?

Note that in Swagger, the API Get request is working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`* - not *`Decode`*. You want to change the `?` into an encoded character before sending it in the URL. `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` does the opposite.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I tried it but now although i can get question with "?" (ex. how?) i cannot get questions with spaces (ex. how are you?)

Comment: A more complete solution exists in `Uri.EscapeDataString`, which should cover both spaces and things like `?`. However, spaces are just `%20`, so you could also just do `.Replace(" ", "%20")`.

Comment: I also tried .Replace no luck ....I will check EscapeDataString  and get back to you ! Thanks again for the reply !